# Why Othman was called Ze-Alnourayn

Tags: sunnah

The third Khalifa Othman ben Afan was called Ze-Alnourayn.

What is the cause for this naming?

Answer (score 2):

The term used is correctly pronounced as *zu-an-noorayn* and this is in Arabic like this:

> ذو النَورين

*zu* means to possess or have.
*noor* is light 
*al-noorayn* means *the two lights*.

The term literally means **one who posses the two lights**.

This was a title of respect given to him by the prophet (sal).

Why was this given? It was because he was married to one of the daughters of the Prophet (sal). Then after she died, he was given the other in marriage as well. Thus he got this title.

Radiyallaahu 'anhum!

Edit: Here's more info (sorry, I should have done this earlier)...

Family tree: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_tree_of_Uthman

Wife 1 - Ruqayyah: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruqayyah_bint_Muhammad

Wife 2 - Umm-Kulthoom: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umm_Kulthum_binte_Muhammad

Comment: But i think you may be wrong. As i know the wives of Othman weren't the Prophet's daughter. They were daughters of Khadijahs'(as)  sister. Do you have another explanation

Comment: @Hadi - What's the source of that claim?

Comment: @SystemDown Check this arabic link http://www.aqaed.com/book/108/banat-03.html

Comment: @SystemDown This is disputed between Shia and Sunnah. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genealogy_of_Khadijah's_daughters